# Images not showing in image gridview from the Bitmap arraylist of image bitmaps

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview, android-gridview, baseadapter

In my android app. I have written an asynctask for client server requests and in the doInBackground part I have obtained the server response to the android app as json. The code is below:

```
String status=sb.toString();
JSONObject jsonResponse1;
try {

/****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
jsonResponse1 = new JSONObject(status);

/***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. Returns null otherwise.*******/
JSONArray jsonMainNode=jsonResponse1.optJSONArray("Android");

/*********** Process each JSON Node ************/
int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();

Log.d("Json Array Length",String.valueOf(lengthJsonArr));

    for(int j1=0;j1<lengthJsonArr;j1++)
    {
        /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(j1);

        /******* Fetch node values **********/
        String index=jsonChildNode.optString("index").toString();
        String imagename=jsonChildNode.optString("imagename").toString();

        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imagename, Base64.DEFAULT);
        decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        imagearraylist.add(decodedByte);
        //This arraylist is an Bitmap arraylist and contains the Bitmaps of two images received from the server..
    }           
  }
catch(Exception ex)
{
       System.out.print(ex);
}
```

This is in the doinBackground section of the asynctask. Now in the onpostexecute part, I have written the following code.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(Gallery.this, "Loading complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    pd.dismiss();

    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter2(getApplicationContext(),imagearraylist));

}
```

ImageAdapter2 is the name of my class in my project.. I will show the code of ImageAdapter2.class

```
package com.example.mygallery;
//skipping the import section

public class ImageAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;       
ArrayList<Bitmap>mImageArray;   

public ImageAdapter2(Context c,ArrayList<Bitmap> imgArray) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext=c;
    mImageArray=imgArray;
    Log.d("Entered into imageadapter2","Success");
    System.out.println("Arr len: "+imgArray.size());

     //Here I get output as 2 in the logcat.Upto this portion the code is executing fine..

 //After this the getView function is not executing. What is the error in this?? Can someone point it out...

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView i = null ;
    int size=mImageArray.size();
    System.out.println("sze: "+size);
    Log.d("Size of Image bitmap array",String.valueOf(size));
    if (convertView == null ) 
    {               
        i = new ImageView(mContext);

        for(int i1=0;i1<size;i1++)
        {

            i.setImageBitmap(mImageArray.get(i1));     
        }

    }
     else 
         i = (ImageView) convertView;           
     return i;

}
```

}

When I try to display the images in the gridview using the imageview. It is not showing any images on my activity. Although there are Bitmaps in the bitmap arraylist..Can someone point out the error in this code..Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getCount() returns 0. It should return mImageArray.size().

Further remove the for loop from getView(). The setImageBitmap() has to be done always. Do it just before return i;

Comment: Since the bitmap arraylist has elements in it, I should use for loop for displaying images one after the other. So how is it done,if the for loop has to be removed from getView(). ? Where should I give the for loop to display the images.? Can you please explain it to me.?

Comment: When I used mImageArray.size() in the getCount() as return statement, out of 4 distinct images in the server, the app displays a single image 4 times. But the other remaining three images are not displayed. I think it is the problem of for loop. Where should I give the for loop to display all the four images of the arraylist.

Comment: Got it working...Removed the for loop and just used like this: i.setImageBitmap(mImageArray.get(position));
       return i; in the getview() and changed like this: public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return mImageArray.size();
 }

Comment: Well you did exactly what i said that had to be done. Good. Now do some orientation changes with your device and realise that yet more work waits...

Comment: What do you mean by Orientation changes?? You mean landscape and portraint orientation in android?  I know that there are many tasks remaining, to make my app look more appealing to the user. Anyway thanks @greenapps for helping me out to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
    /******* Fetch node values **********/
    String index=jsonChildNode.optString("index").toString();
    String imagename=jsonChildNode.optString("imagename").toString();

    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imagename, Base64.DEFAULT);
    decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    imagearraylist.add(decodedByte);
```

This part does not look good. You are getting imagename from json as a string & trying to convert that to a Bitmap.
Instead, try this approach:
-Get image name or URL from JSON ( in this rest call )
-Then, get the image from the url in a background thread / async task / service.

You can find the best way to do @ http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Or, if you want to go one step ahead, refer picasso
https://github.com/square/picasso
It is the one I referred for one of my previous projects.

Comment: The code which you have mentioned works with no error. I donot want to download or get the image to my phone as a jpg image from any url in asynctask. Instead I only want to just display the Bitmaps in the Bitmap arraylist. That's my primary concern here. By the way I have tried your suggested way in one of my projects earlier and it works fine. But here the situation or the logic of the app which I'm trying to implement is different. So, I only want to know the errors in my coding and not any other alternative suggestions. I hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: Your imagename is contains Base64 content, means getting from server as Base64 ?

Comment: it's actually the image data not image name. That means the image converted into Base64 string and then saved to the server. This Base64 string is received as output from server in the form of json..

Comment: Just try to create the image @ server itself from that Base64 content. Just for debugging purpose & to make sure it is a valid Base64 image content.

Comment: It's a valid Base64 image. I have checked it..There is no error in that portion...

Comment: If you know the error in my code, then please mention it to me. Otherwise stop asking me such silly and nonsense questions, like do this way, do another way etc..I need to clear the errors as fast as possible, so please help me if you know the answer. Otherwise please stop blabbering..

Comment: Just try to add the bitmap to an ImageView with a static height & width( say 100dp x 100dp ) & see whether it is showing. Try with one image. If it works, probably the issue would be with Gridview layout specifications.